# Function with input prints out nothing

Tags: python, pygame, piano, music-notation

Ok so I'm trying to get `z.ExNote()` to print out an image (of an 8th note) onto a page of sheet music for an app I'm building. Basically every variable just has to do with the (x,y) coordinates of where the note is to be placed. `.ExNote()` is a function inside a class `Note` which translates 5 variables of the `Note` object `(Num, staff, measure, note, notetype)` into an x,y coordinate for the image to be placed on. This whole mess takes care of 4 variables for you so you can theoretically input the note `c,d,e,f,g,a,b` and it will print it out at the beginning of the staff, then the next note you input will be  the  next position which happens to be 17 pixels to the right and so on.

```
StaffL = {0: 'nada', 1: '1R', 2: '1L', 3:'2R',
      4: '2L', 5: '3R', 6: '3L', 7: '4R', 8: '4L'}

pygame.display.set_caption("Piano App")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:

    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done=True  



screen.fill(white)
DrawGrandStaffAll()
TS(4,4)
notetypeZ = 'Ethnote'
g=0
while g < 8:
    g+=1
    staff = StaffL[g]
    measureZ = 0
    while measureZ<6:
        measureZ += 1
        wnoteZ = 0
        while wnoteZ<8:
            wnoteZ += 1
            noteZ=(input("\n\nWhat note \nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\na\nb\nc2\nd2\n"))
            z = Note(int(wnoteZ), repr(staff), int(measureZ), repr(noteZ), repr(notetypeZ))
            z.ExNote()
            pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

If I just type in what `z` ends up being equal to (`Note(1, '1R', 1, 'c', 'Ethnote')`) and then do `z.Exnote()`, it works(my note is printed onto the sheet music). But it doesn't work when I do it like this. I also ran this code in a separate window and printed out z to make sure it's not some technical error/typo and the output is exactly what I want it to be. So the problem isn't the variable and it's not some technical error. I'm assuming the error has something to do with the input because that's the only thing that changes between manually inputing `z=Note(1, '1R', 1, 'c', 'Ethnote')` and using this code to build the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python 2 or 3.  If you use Python 2, input() tries to evaluate the expression you type.  raw_input() which I believe you want here returns the string.